# Can access facebook object via web, but can't do it with API

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get info about object by id (mostly links, photos, statuses..). And I find that there are some posts that I can access from a browser(I can share, comment, like..), but for some reason I'm getting

{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request.", 
    "type": "GraphMethodException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}

while accessing the same object through API (either via Graph Explorer, or with PHP SDK).
In Graph Explorer I've tried all permissions. My FB App has no restrictions and there are lot of posts, that I can GET.

What can be the problem, that API returns me an error instead of a post, that I can freely see from my account on facebook.com?

P.S. If I try to get /user-id/feed of the user, whos post I can't access, it often gives me an empty array data:[]

Comment: "It doesn't work! What can be the problem?" What query have you tried?

Comment: I really don't want to put here link, but.. Guess I need to do..
I will substitute fb for (facebook.com) and graph for (graph.facebook.com), so here are my tries as example
1) fb/shahar.smirin/posts/10152129450343701 (I can see it)

2) graph/10152129450343701 (error)
3) graph/508058700_10152129450343701 (error)

*btw, what's the difference between 2 and 3? API gives different results for graph/userid_objectid and graph/object_id

Answer (score 1):

"Unsupported Get Request" means you've requested something which can't be returned to you.

Some possible reasons, in order of how likely they are in my experience, are:

- Object has some privacy or demographic restrictions and you haven't provided an access token from someone who meets those restrictions
- Object was deleted
- Object doesn't exist
- Object is of a type not supported in the API at all

Comment: Via API I use ACCESS_TOKEN which is mine. That's why I clarified, that I am able to get this object directly on Facebook.com/object_id. So, object is not deleted and exists, the type is photo or link and truly supported. Restrictions? All permissions are on and all possible restrictions are down.

Comment: That doesn't rule out the most likely cause which is that you're not allowed to see the object via the API due to privacy or demographic restrictions - if a user who posted the content has disabled all platform apps, you'll never get their data via the API

Comment: So, as I can understand, there are some restrictions, that figuratively says: "We won't let you get the information, because you're using API"?

I mean, there's nothing I can do about this anyway?

Comment: Without knowing exactly what you're trying to access, where you got the ID from, who you're trying to access it as, etc, it's hard to be sure, but it seems likely that the API is simply not allowing you to see what you're asking for - the API is not expected to have parity with facebook.com, there's different data available, different privacy rules etc

Comment: In the comments to my question there are specified links, and object ids, that I'm trying to access. Thanks. =)

Comment: Where did you get those IDs? if you made a call that returned you an object ID, in most cases you should be able to access that object ID - if you're manually attempting to craft IDs based on knowing the poster and the share ID or something that's probably not going to work

Comment: You're right, I haven't got the IDs by calling API method. Instead, they are grabbed as <form> <input> field "fb_param". They are called "target_fbid" and "actor... 

But my question is not about IDs. I mean, I can see the post on the site, by using ID as an URL, but can't get it via GRAPH API, through my access_token.

So, for now, the only question that I'm interested in: can I ever get this post through API?